# Returning primary key on INSERT with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, database, odbc, pyodbc

I have a program inserting a bunch of data into an SQL database. The data consists of *Reports*, each having a number of *Tags*.

A *Tag* has a field *report_id*, which is a reference to the primary key of the relevant *Report*.

Now, each time I insert the data, there can be 200 *Reports* or even more, each maybe having 400 *Tags*. So in pseudo-code I'm now doing this:

```
for report in reports:
    cursor_report = sql('INSERT report...')
    cursor_report.commit()
    report_id = sql('SELECT @@IDENTITY')

    for tag in report:
        cursor_tag += sql('INSERT tag, report_id=report_id')
    cursor_tag.commit()
```

I don't like this for a couple of reasons. Mostly i don't like the `SELECT @@IDENTITY` statement.

1. Wouldn't this mean that if another process were inserting data at the right moment then the statement would return the wrong primary key?
2. I would rather like the `INSERT report...` to return the inserted primary key, is that possible?

Since I currently have to commit between reports the program "pauses" during these moments. If I could commit everything at the end then it would greatly reduce the time spent. I have been considering creating a seperate field in *Report* used for identification so I could `report_id = (SELECT id FROM reports WHERE seperate_field=?)` or something in the *Tags*, but that doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't this mean that if another process were inserting data at the right moment then the ["SELECT @@IDENTITY"] statement would return the wrong primary key?

No. The database engine keeps track of the last identity value inserted *for each connection* and returns the appropriate value for the connection on which the `SELECT @@IDENTITY` statement is executed.

Comment: Oh alright, I thought it returned the last primary key inserted wherever by whatever connection - I have only an intermediate understanding of SQL. Thank you for the answer, this at least means that my method should work as I want it to, even if it's a little slower than I'd like :)